# Cordova: choppy contents after adding dynamic data

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova

I am creating an android chat application using cordova, everything gonna fine on the browser, but when I wrapped it into webview using ***cordova*** it display choppy contents when i add contents at runtime.

Note that the nothing on the page has a css3 animation, also i am only using native touch scroll, and this issue appear only on devices with android version 4.4+.

Sample code:

```
var element=document.getElementById("conversation_messages_container");
element.innerHTML=element.innerHTML+"<div class='bubble'>this is a bubble content</div>";
```

**Picture taken from Samsung S4**

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can we see how you are adding the new data and have you tested on other devices and/or emulator?

Comment: @JamesWong, I already edited the question.

Comment: Looks pretty innocent. So you've tested on other devices and all those that are running Android 4.4+ has this same problem? Also what version of Cordova is this?

Comment: @JamesWong, in fact i test it on 5 devices, with android versions 4.1,4.2,4.4.2,4.4.3,5 and this issue appear only on devices with version 4.4+ . and i am using cordova 3.6.4

Comment: The reason why 4.4 can be a problem is because WebView has been replaced by Chromium. You may need newer versions of Cordova that fully supports it.

Comment: @JamesWong, I will try to update it to 4.0 and tell you about the result. Thanks.